# Why am I getting the error message "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction'"?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I can't seem to receive a `Promise` from `createAsyncThunk` function from `Redux-toolkit`
I'm fairly new to Typescript and I'm struggling to figure out why it's giving me
`Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction<Student, number, {}>'` error even though the promise does get returned if I remove the typing.
Here is my `createAsyncThunk` f-n

```
export const getStudentByIdRequest = createAsyncThunk<Student, number>(
  'student/getStudentByIdRequest',
  async (id, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await instance.get(`student/${id}/`)
      return data
    } catch (err) {
      let error: AxiosError = err
      if (error) {
        return rejectWithValue({
          message: `Error. Error code ${error.response?.status}`,
        })
      }
      throw err
    }
  }
)
```

And that is how I dispatch it from my `React` component

```
dispatch(getStudentByIdRequest(userId)).then((res) => console.log(res))
```

The error appears where I try to call `then` on the thunk

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your `dispatch` does not take types for thunks into account and thus the return type is typed incorrectly. Please use the actual `Dispatch` type from the store as decsribed in [the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-dispatch-type):

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>() // Export a hook that can be reused to resolve types
```

and then use `useAppDispatch` instead of `useDispatch` in your component.

Comment: I did that and I also had to change   `middleware: [thunk] as const`  to  `middleware: getDefaultMiddleware()` in  `configureStore` function and now I get an error saying 
 ` ReferenceError: Cannot access 'userReducer' before initialization  `
This error is exactly why I gave up on using  `useAppDispatch` in the first place

Comment: Nevermind I got it resolved by moving my `Axios` interceptor function from from `apiConfig.ts` file to `index.ts` as suggested here https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/687#issuecomment-671645874

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 22):

Another potential solution for this could be using `ThunkDispatch` type instead of plain `Dispatch`, as plain `Dispatch` is not meant to be handling async stuff.

Defining reusable `useAppThunkDispatch` hook in store.ts:

```
import { Action, ThunkDispatch, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        blog: blogSlice,
    },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type ThunkAppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<RootState, void, Action>;

export const useAppThunkDispatch = () => useDispatch<ThunkAppDispatch>();
```

You can then use `useAppThunkDispatch` hook in your app just like `useAppDispatch` or `useDispatch` hook.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was facing was very similar to this, I was working on something based on the Redux Toolkit documentation and the following simply didn't work:

```js
let dispatch = useDispatch()
```

The point was that the tutorial uses the useDispatch() on a personalized hook, which is exported as `useAppDispatch()`

```js
import { useAppDispatch } from "app/hooks";
```

If you use the right importation and types you're gonna be able to solve this issue.