# Redux Toolkit Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction'

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have an async action created with `createAsyncThunk`. [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-then-issue-forked-mw5hc?file=/src/store/counter/reducer.ts:82-317)
Now I bind the dispatch to it with `bindActionCreators` and I expose the action with a custom hook. [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-then-issue-forked-mw5hc?file=/src/store/counter/hook.ts:223-303)
If now I try to use the async action, the `then` is not a recognized property and I get an error [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-then-issue-forked-mw5hc?file=/src/components/Counter/index.tsx:217-270)

`Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction<number, number, {}>'`

Do you have any ideas?
My dispatch is custom typed and therefore everything should be correct

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this : [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811401/property-then-does-not-exist-on-type-asyncthunkaction-redux-toolkit)

Comment: probably, but I did what was suggested, and it's not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting the error message "Property 'then' does not exist on type 'AsyncThunkAction'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811401/why-am-i-getting-the-error-message-property-then-does-not-exist-on-type-asyn)